# Dotnet Services Lifetime DI

Tags: c#, .net, events, dependency-injection

I know how life injection works with three types, transient, singleton and scoped. I also know how each and everyone of those works.

In a scoped case I know that it creates a new instance of a service for every request, but I don't know what I can consider a request to use scoped injection.

I know that a httpRequest via controller is a lifetime request, but I'm workin with event on kafka, and I want to know if the lifetime of me consuming a event and doing everything I need can be also consider as a request lifetime, so I can work properly with DI.

That been said, I want to know if I use some services injected as scoped in my process after consuming a event on kafka, this services will be disposable by GC in the end of the process, like it does with a http request.

Comment: What exactly as you doing with Kafka? Please clarify what your question is.

Comment: my question is .. A kafka consumer event is also a lifetime request? like http request via controller. That been said i wanna know if i use some services injected as scoped in my process after consuming a event on kafka, this services will be available by GC in the end of the proccess

Comment: You consume an immutable event from Kafka. I fail to understand how this is related to the lifetime of any request you make to some other component.

Comment: i consume something, and fire a event, that is caught by a handler, my handler need to do some stuff, like find some data on DB, or redis, this require my handler to use DI to get the services. I wanna know if this whole "proccess" is like a request proccess or if the services i use on handler will not be "killed" if i use scoed type

Comment: Is the event handled before the original request has completed? In general, the instances are eventually being collected when there are no references to them any longer.

Comment: In this case i don't have any http request, the only way a receive a "request" is via kafka, other api publish an info, and this one consumes it to access and find the right data on redis. That is the reasson i duno how the scoped will behave

Comment: So then it's either a singleton or not?

Comment: I'm treating like Singleton, but i don't know if it's behaves in a way that i can use scoped... you know what i mean? that is exactly my doubt, if i could use scope or only singleton